# Multiple input output channel wiring by sounddevice

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, audio-streaming, pyaudio

I am trying to make input-output pairs by sounddevice module on Raspberry Pi with 4 USB-soundcard. I made up to two wired channels but keep failing from three. Ideally I want to build up to 4 channel real-streaming(latency is not important.)

I used callback and with:, it seems work fine up to two channels. Please find below code:

```py
import sounddevice as sd

def wirecall(indata,outdata,*stuff):
    #sd.CallbackStop()
    outdata[:]=indata

with sd.Stream(device=0,channels=1,callback=wirecall,samplerate=44100):
    with sd.Stream(device=1, channels=1, callback=wirecall, samplerate=44100):
        while True:
                response=input()
                if response in ('', 'q', 'Q'):
                    break
```

This works fine but as soon as I add one more with: it doesn't work. Is this Raspberry or Sounddevice module's limit? I tried with PyAudio as well but same result.

When I try to open 3 streams below error messages happen.

```
>>> with sd.Stream(device=3,channels=1,callback=wirecall,samplerate=44100):
...     with sd.Stream(device=1,channels=1,callback=wirecall,samplerate=44100):
...         with sd.Stream(device=2, channels=1,callback=wirecall,samplerate=44100):
...             while True:
...                 response=input()
...                 if response in ('', 'q', 'Q'):
...                     break
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 1662, in __init__
    **_remove_self(locals()))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 780, in __init__
    'Error opening {0}'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 2570, in _check
    raise PortAudioError(errormsg, err, hosterror_info)
sounddevice.PortAudioError: Error opening Stream: Unanticipated host error [PaErrorCode -9999]: 'Broken pipe' [ALSA error -32]
>>>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error message or what is the expected vs actual behaviour of your code?

Comment: Hi, sorry I missed it. It says 'Broken pipe' [Alsa error -32]. I will attach it on the post.

Comment: Just in case I tried re-installed my Rpi but it happens same.